# TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied overwrites is not an Array or Collection of Permission Overwrites. Discord v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

```
module.exports = {
    config: {
        name: 'lock',
        aliases: ['lk'], 
        description: "",
        category: "Admin"
    },
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
    const Discord = require('discord.js')

    if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES", "MANAGE_CHANNELS")) {
    return message.reply(`<@${message.author.id}>, You do not have the permissions`);
    } else if(!message.guild.me.permissions.has("MANAGE_MESSAGES", "MANAGE_CHANNELS")) {
      return message.reply("I don't have Permissions")
    } else {
    
    message.channel.overwritePermissions(message.guild.everyone, {
    SEND_MESSAGES: false,
    ADD_REACTIONS: false
    });

     const embedLock = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     .setTitle(`Channel successfully blocked! Use !ynlock to Unlock the channel`)
     .setColor("RED")
     const msg = await message.channel.send(embedLock)
    }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make the !lock command block everyone's messages, but when I use the command, the bot sends the embed message:

```
     const embedLock = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     .setTitle(`Channel successfully blocked! Use !ynlock to Unlock the channel`)
     .setColor("RED")
     const msg = await message.channel.send(embedLock)
```

But it does not block messages, and sends this error in the terminal:

```
TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied overwrites is not an Array or Collection of Permission Overwrites
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
message.channel.overwritePermissions(message.guild.everyone, 
  {
    SEND_MESSAGES: false,
    ADD_REACTIONS: false
   });
```

Is actually the format for [`Channel.updateOverwrite()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CategoryChannel?scrollTo=updateOverwrite). For [`Channel.overwritePermissions()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CategoryChannel?scrollTo=overwritePermissions), use this instead:

```js
message.channel.overwritePermissions([
  {
     id: message.author.id,
     deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'ADD_REACTIONS'],
  },
]);
```