# Lock Command Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I recently made a lock command for discord.js. However whenever I run the command I get an error. Here is the code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: "lock",
    description: "Lock",

    async run(client, message, args) {
        if (!message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send('You can\'t use that!')
        function lock(message) {
            let channel = message.channel;
            const Guild = client.guilds.cache.get("751424392420130907");

            if (!Guild) return console.error("Couldn't find the guild.");

            const Role = Guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Verified");
            channel.overwritePermissions(
                Role, {
                'SEND_MESSAGES': false
            },
                'Competitive has Ended'
            )
        }
        lock(message)
        message.channel.send('Channel Locked')
    }
}
```

As I had mentioned earlier that whenever I run this command I get the following error:

```
(node:1354) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied overwrites is not an Array or Collection of Permission Overwrites.
    at TextChannel.overwritePermissions (/home/runner/SweatyBeautifulHelpfulWorker/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/GuildChannel.js:208:9)
    at lock (/home/runner/SweatyBeautifulHelpfulWorker/commands/lock.js:14:11)
    at Object.run (/home/runner/SweatyBeautifulHelpfulWorker/commands/lock.js:21:1)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/SweatyBeautifulHelpfulWorker/index.js:77:42)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at Client.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/runner/SweatyBeautifulHelpfulWorker/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/runner/SweatyBeautifulHelpfulWorker/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/runner/SweatyBeautifulHelpfulWorker/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/runner/SweatyBeautifulHelpfulWorker/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
(node:1354) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1354) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[WS => Shard 0] [HeartbeatTimer] Sending a heartbeat.
[WS => Shard 0] Heartbeat acknowledged, latency of 44ms.
(node:1354) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied overwrites is not an Array or Collection of Permission Overwrites.
    at TextChannel.overwritePermissions (/home/runner/SweatyBeautifulHelpfulWorker/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/GuildChannel.js:208:9)
    at lock (/home/runner/SweatyBeautifulHelpfulWorker/commands/lock.js:14:11)
    at Object.run (/home/runner/SweatyBeautifulHelpfulWorker/commands/lock.js:21:1)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/SweatyBeautifulHelpfulWorker/index.js:77:42)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at Client.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/runner/SweatyBeautifulHelpfulWorker/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/runner/SweatyBeautifulHelpfulWorker/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/runner/SweatyBeautifulHelpfulWorker/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/runner/SweatyBeautifulHelpfulWorker/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
(node:1354) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
```

Can you help me out in solving this problem? thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at the [Discord,js docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) where it states what parameters [`TextChannel.overwritePermissions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=overwritePermissions) takes? It's also state in your error that the method requires an Array or Collection of overwrites, but you aren't passing an Array or Collection

Comment: I would take a look at. **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63778967/typeerror-invalid-type-supplied-overwrites-is-not-an-array-or-collection-of-p**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError \[INVALID\_TYPE\]: Supplied overwrites is not an Array or Collection of Permission Overwrites. Discord v12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63778967/typeerror-invalid-type-supplied-overwrites-is-not-an-array-or-collection-of-p)

Comment: I tried but keep getting the same error

Answer (score 2):

You should do this, your code seems lengthy :

```
 if (!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Moderator')) return;
 message.channel.updateOverwrite(message.channel.guild.roles.everyone, { SEND_MESSAGES: false })
 message.channel.send(`Successfully locked **${message.channel.name}**`)
```

Replace `message.channel.guild.roles.everyone` from your roles.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call the following lines to remove the send permissions on the current channel:

```
const Role = guild.roles.find("name", "Verified ");

message.channel.overwritePermissions(role,{ 'SEND_MESSAGES': false })
```

If you wanna make an unlock channel command, simply add this under the command:

```
const Role = guild.roles.find("name", "Verified ");

message.channel.overwritePermissions(role,{ 'SEND_MESSAGES': true})
```

Answer (score 0):

you should also use `updateOverwrite` instead of `overwritePermissions`.

Example:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "lock",
    description: "Lock",

    run(client, message, args) {
       const targetChannel = message.mentions.channels.first() || message.channel;

        // Guild ID is the same as the everyone role ID
        const everyoneID = message.guild.id;

        targetChannel.updateOverwrite(everyoneID, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: false,
        });

        targetChannel.send(`**${targetChannel.name}** has been locked :lock:`);
    }
}
```

There is also no need for it to be an async function since you are not using await in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not how you update the permission instead of this:

```
channel.overwritePermissions(
            Role, {
            'SEND_MESSAGES': false
        },
            'Competitive has Ended'
        )
```

use this:

```
channel.overwritePermissions([
        {
        id: roleId,
        deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES']
        }]
        ,'Competitive has Ended'
    )
```

source [discord.js documentation#overwritePermissions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=overwritePermissions)

Answer (score 0):

This code below might help you

````
channel.overwritePermissions(
    [
        {
            id: roleId,
            deny: [
                'SEND_MESSAGES'
            ]
        }
    ]
        , 'Mark my question'
)```
````